# Sporting beard Vs keeping beard

Tags: expressions

For non-native speakers of English language the usage, someone sporting beard may appear odd.They wonder as to why "someone keeping the the beard well trimmed or leaving beard matted" is not acceptable in standard English.Native speakers of English language are requested to give their views in the usage connected with keeping beard / sporting beard / growing beard.Do all these options are acceptable?

Comment: Could you rephrase that?

Comment: Yes ,I mean someone keeping beard or growing beard are also acceptable in standard English.

Comment: I'd just say somebody ***has*** a beard.

Comment: Then what about someone sporting beard.

Comment: The relevant definition of [sport](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sport) is *to display or wear, usually ostentatiously*. So you can definitely say somebody is *sporting* a beard, but saying somebody *has* a beard is much more common, and can be used for anybody with a beard, whether or not they are proud of it and keep it neat.

Comment: I come across several times, especially while reading fiction, someone sporting beard,I thought that sporting beard is the standard expression in English.(I am a non-native speaker of English language).

Comment: @Margana roll back the edits, that wasn't always there...

Answer (score 3):

The following are all acceptable English. They mean slightly different things:

- "Sporting a beard" as Peter Shor says, means to "display or wear" a beard, usually ostentatiously. It just means that a person has a beard. You probably wouldn't use the word if they were trying to conceal the beard.
- "Growing a beard" means to go from not having a beard to having a beard. You don't say someone is "growing a beard" if they have had it for years.
- "Keeping a beard" means they have had the beard for a while and are not getting rid of it. "He kept his beard all through summer".
- "Keeping a beard trimmed" isn't the same. It means he made sure the beard was always in a trimmed condition.
- "Leaving a beard matted" means that you are not grooming the beard. Beards tend to go 'matted' if not groomed, so this person is not doing the grooming.

Comment: Your answer is really helpful.

Comment: Moe generally, _sport_ as a verb shows up in many pieces of journalism where its meaning is simply _have_, but the writer is under the impression that _sport_ is an intrinsically superior word. I can't count the number of times at the computer magazines where I worked that a product review would say that a particular PC "sports" a hard drive of a certain capacity, a graphics board of a certain type, and memory of a certain quantity. None of the sported items were visible, of course, which made _sport_ a rather hollow word choice. Some instances of beard "sporting" may be similarly thoughtless.